# Java Applets Not Loading; "Start: App Not Initialized"

Tags: java, applet, awt, runtime-error

I don't quite get this. I downloaded a class, put it on my website, and then created an HTML page with the basic applet tags, and the app showed up just fine.

But when I downloaded the source code and compiled it myself, all that shows up on my site is a blank applet with the error on the bottom of the browser, "start: app not initialized."

I tried writing a simpler code, such as

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*;

public class GuiExamplar extends Applet { 
    Button okButton; 

    public void init() { 
    setLayout(null); 
        okButton = new Button("A button"); 
        okButton.setBounds(20,20,100,30); 
    add(okButton); 
    }
}
```

And it does the same thing. It compiles just fine, but doesn't show up on my browser.

Actually, any of my browsers. I tried Opera, Firefox, and Chrome. But the applet just shows a blank gray square.

Comment: That code does not compile because nameField is not declared anywhere.  Are you sure you uploaded a successfully compiled class file?

Comment: That was a typo, there wasn't that line in the file I compiled.
And yes, it compiled just fine.

Comment: Why is your layout null? I see this alot when people have problems. What does a null layout give you?

Comment: Since the question in your post might be inferred as "Should I be coding applets yet?" the answer is "no".  If you have a different question, you should ask it.  Otherwise I might enter that as an answer.

Comment: Don't blame me. Tell me moderators to make the accept button more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This class is not launching as an applet as it does not extend JApplet or Applet.

Even when this is fixed, nothing will appear in the applet client. Applets do not call the main method but rather init. Also don't create a new Frame for applet components - add them to the applet container itself.